# database transaction conflict resolution

Tags: transactions, rdbms

How DBMS resolve conflict in transactions and when it happens?

For example if I have a record

```
id  name  value
 1   N1    VAL1
```

And I have isolation level lower than `snapshot isolation` or `serializable` (repeatable read or read commited)

**First case.** I've got two transactions.
First transaction `T1` updates `name` field to `N2`

```
update table set name = 'N2' where id = '1'
```

Second transaction `T2` updates field `value` to `VAL2`. It completes before first transaction.

```
update table set value = 'VAL2' where id = '1'
```

As far as I understand both transactions should not conflict as they change different fields of the records. *Am I right? Or there will be conflict as the state of the record changed by transaction `T2`*?

**Second case.** I've got two transactions. 
First transaction `T1` updates `name` field to `N2`.

```
update table set name = 'N2' where id = '1'
```

Second transaction `T2` updates `name` field to `N3`.

```
update table set name = 'N3' where id = '1'
```

And again it completes before first transaction. As far as I understand it should be a conflict as the state of `name` field for the first transaction is not as it was in the beginning of it. *So what will happen? Transaction aborts and retry? Or it will abort and rollback?*

Answer (score 4):

You're asking how RDBMSs implement the 'I' (Isolation) part of the ACID principle.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)

Depends on the RDBMS, but SQL Server uses locking to achieve it.
(This should also hold true for Oracle, Postgres, MySQL using InnoDB but NOT MyISAM).

The transactions are processed in the order they're received.
Due to this, and locking, in both of your examples the second transaction cannot possibly complete before the first.

1st example:

The first transaction acquires an exclusive lock on the row.
The second transaction requests an exclusive lock on the same row, but must wait.
The first transaction completes and releases its exclusive lock.
Now name = 'N2', value = 'VAL1'
The second transaction now acquires the exclusive lock on the row.
The second transaction completes and releases its lock.
Now name = 'N2', value = 'VAL2'

2nd example:

The first transaction acquires an exclusive lock on the row.
The second transaction requests an exclusive lock on the same row, but must wait.
The first transaction completes and releases its exclusive lock.
Now name = 'N2'
The second transaction now acquires the exclusive lock on the row.
Due to snapshot isolation, the second transaction is rolled back as the value of name has changed since the transaction began. Its locks are released.
Now name = 'N2'

Re-running the second transaction at this point would result in a successful update of name to 'N3' (assuming no other concurrent transactions on that row).

Comment: Oh, my bad. Sorry. Yes, I understand that in `snapshot isolation` and `serializable` it should be sequential. What I meant that I don't have that level of  isolation. Edited question.

Comment: Do you have a specific RDBMS in mind? In SQL Server writers always block writers (they always require exclusive locks) regardless of the isolation level. I'd expect the others to behave the same. If the second transaction was a read rather than an update then you'd see different things depending on the isolation level it's running in.

Comment: Well I don't have any particular DBMS in mind. I though there exist some common ground between them.

Comment: Well, they should all behave pretty much as I've described.

Comment: I meant the case when I do not have neither `snapshot isolation` nor `serializable`. Phantom reads, etc. would not appear if the were processed one after another

Comment: They don't apply to concurrent _updates_. If you need to know what happens when the second session is a read, I can add examples for each isolation level to my answer.

Comment: Please do. I always thought that isolation levels affect updates too.